# Getting 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ini4j/Ini' error after succesfully compiling source file from the CLI

Tags: java, exception, noclassdeffounderror, ini4j

Background:
I am trying to use ini4j for the purpose of parsing config files in the ini format.

I run the command:
javac -classpath ini4j-0.5.4.jar   Driver.java
and the compilation goes smoothly...however when I attempt to run the program running:
java Driver
I get this error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ini4j/Ini
    at Clock.main(Clock.java:13)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ini4j.Ini
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 1 more`

From what I understand this error is a product of the jvm being able to find the class file being referenced in the error and failing.  I checked the ini4j jar file and confirmed that the Ini.class file does in fact exist.   Can anyone please tell me what am I missing here ?

The following is my source code:

```
import java.util.Map;   
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import org.ini4j.* ;
public class Driver{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("running in Clock-J main()");
        String fileName = "./test.ini" ;
        File fileObject = new File(fileName);
        try{
            Ini ini = new Ini(fileObject);
        }catch(IOException e){
            String exception = e.toString() ;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer  for my situation appears to be:
    java -cp .:ini4j-0.5.4.jar Driver
Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction guys!!!!  Using an IDE causes one to forget stuff like this.   I really appreciate it!!!!  Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You also need to specify the -classpath option when you run the program. Java will not automatically pick up the jar files that you passed when you compiled your code.

Answer (score -1):

Look at *Elipse->Properties->JavaBuildPath->Libraries*
list of extended JARs have to be in CLASSPATH

[please check for more info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaOkx.png)